# I had sexual intercource during the day of Ramadhan but forgot it breaks the fast

Tags: sawm, sex, ramadan, hanafi, kaffarah

I had sexual intercource with my wife during Ramadhan but we both forgot that it breaks the fast and only remembered at the end. Do I have to do kaffarah? Does this count in forgetfulness? **I follow hanafi school of thought**

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hanafis having sexual intercourse out of forgetfulness does not invaliate the fast, and hence neither Qada nor Kaffarah are required. This is based on analogy with the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1933) of eating\drinking in forgetfulness.

> فإن أكل الصائم أو شرب أو جامع ناسيا لم يفطر
>
> If the person who is fasting (ṣā’im) eats, drinks or has sexual intercourse
> out of forgetfulness, he has not broken his fast.
>
> <sup>— [Mukhtasar Al-Qudoori](https://shamela.ws/book/124336/52) -  ([English Translation](https://openmaktaba.com/wp-content/uploads/books/popular-books/The-Mukhtasar-Al-Quduri-A-Manual-of-Islamic-Law-According-to-the-Hanafi-School.pdf#page=129))</sup>

Also see [Radd al-Muhtar ala al-Dur al-Mukhtar](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/1050), [Fatawa 'Alamgiri](https://shamela.ws/book/21640/201) , [Badaa’i’ al-Sanaa’i’](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/413), [al-Hidaayah Sharh al-Bidaayah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11820/164) etc.

Note that according to other madhabs this case may require Qada (Maliki) or even Kaffarah (Hanbali).

Comment: Also see: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/50017/he-masturbated-not-knowing-that-it-invalidates-the-fast